# ACF - плагин, цикл модального окна

Tags: wordpress, acf

Как мне задать правильный цикл для модального окна в записи ?

нужно вывести 3 блока товара (каждый блок одна запись) при клике на товар открывается модальное окно с описанием товара и слайдер. Как сделать что разные картины можно было добавить на каждый продукт ?

Я установил платную версию ACF, и попробовал через repeat, но выводится только последняя картина на всех слайдерах, хотя записи разные, для каждого товара одна запись

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade product-info-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                      <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                          <div class="product-area">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <div class="product-slider">
                              <?php if(get_field('modal_slider')): ?>
                                <div class="flexslider">
                                  <ul class="slides">
                                  <?php while(has_sub_field('modal_slider')): ?>
                                    <li>
                                      <img src="<?php the_sub_field('em_img'); ?>" alt="" />
                                    </li>
                                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                                  </ul>
                                </div> 
                                <?php endif; ?>                                                            
                              </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="product-information">
                                  <h1>Название продукта</h1>
                                  <hr>
                                  <p>Очень длинный-длинный текст</p>
                                  <p>Цена: 756874 грн</p>
                                  <p>Очень длинный-длинный текст</p>
                                  <div class="product-buy-btn">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btn-buy-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sendRequest">Купить</button>
                                  </div>
                                  <hr>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                              <div class="product-content">
                                <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.</p>
                                   <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты.</p>
                                   <p>+380 00 00 00 00</p>                              
                                   <p>+380 00 00 00 00</p>
                                   <h3>Далеко-далеко за словесными.</h3>
                                   <hr>
                                   <h4>Далеко-далеко за словесными.</h4>
                                     <table class="table table-striped">
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>John</td>
                                          <td>Doe</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>Mary</td>
                                          <td>Moe</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>July</td>
                                          <td>Dooley</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>July</td>
                                          <td>Dooley</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>July</td>
                                          <td>Dooley</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td>July</td>
                                          <td>Dooley</td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>                               
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Comment: Согласно правилам сообщества, вы должны показать свой код. Гадать смысла нет.

Comment: Спасибо, добавил

Comment: А модальное окно где?

Comment: Добавил, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: А сайт доступен?

Comment: пока на тестовом

http://lemlab.com.ua/montajnik-wp/%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C/

Comment: есть какие то идеи ?

Answer (score 0):

Вы создаёте три модальных окна, все с одинаковым `id="MyModal"`, что вообще-то запрещено по стандарту. А дальше вы на все товары на странице вешаете одинаковый `data-target="#myModal"`. И какого результата вы хотите? На какую кнопку "Подробнее" не нажми, всегда будет выведено одно и то же модальное окно.

Вам надо присвоить модальным окнам разные id, например "MyModal_1", "MyModal_2", "MyModal_3". И в коде кнопок "Подробнее" указывать, соответственно, `data-target="#myModal_1"`, `data-target="#myModal_2"`, `data-target="#myModal_3"`.

Comment: У меня однa модальная окно в коде, по циклу шаблон повторяется, проблема в том что как вывести информацию в цикле правильно что при добавление информации не повторялся. один продукт одна запись, и все записи в одной рубрике

Comment: Используйте переменную цикла, чтобы выводить разные Id и data-target

Answer (score -1):

Проблема решена с помощью

$ID = get_the_ID();

Возвращает ID текущего поста в цикле.